# Evaluating sizeof long array of SIZE_MAX elements

Tags: c, sizeof

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(){
    size_t cnt = SIZE_MAX;
    size_t sz = sizeof(long[cnt]);
    printf("%zu\n", sz);
}
```

`6.5.3.4/p2`:

> If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the
> operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the
> result is an integer constant.

The question is if such too large `sizeof` evaluation well defined? Since `size_t` is `unsigned`, the Standard guarantees that `unsigned` integer overflow has well-defined behavior (unlike `signed` where implementation defined signal might be raised).

The main issue I'm confused about is that

```
size_t sz = sizeof(long[SIZE_MAX]); //error: size of unnamed array is too large
```

does not even compile [**Godbolt live example**](https://godbolt.org/z/5xdcxhKoc)

Comment: There is `SIZE_MAX`, might better illustrate the point.

Comment: `long[cnt]` is probably larger than an allowed array type.

Comment: @Barmar don't quite get the point... We'll got an overflow anyway

Comment: @KamilCuk Good point, fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof (long[SIZE_MAX])` won't compile because attempting to form the type `long[SIZE_MAX]` is a constraint violation. From §6.2.5 28 of the C23 draft standard:

> A complete type shall have a size that is less than or equal to `SIZE_MAX`.

The constraint in question is not listed under a *"Constraints"* heading, so compilers are not *required* to issue a diagnostic for this. In this case both GCC and Clang choose to fail and issue an error message, but more generally `sizeof (long[SIZE_MAX])` has undefined behavior since it violates a "shall" outside of an explicit constraints clause. But I'd like to think that *reasonable* implementations would fail to compile with an error like this when an attempt to declare an array which cannot be supported is made.

It appears that this language did not appear in previous standards, but the Standards Committee determined [*"...that all interpret the current standard that huge objects make the behavior implicitly undefined."*](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2838.htm) The Committee views this change not as introducing an undefined behavior, but as a clarification that makes this explicit.

Comment: This is good! I wonder if refusing to compile `sizeof(char[SIZE_MAX])` is implementation defined or not though. It's certainly _"... or equal to `SIZE_MAX`"_.

Comment: Changing to `sizeof(long[SIZE_MAX/sizeof(long)])` gives a slightly different error `size '18446744073709551608' of array exceeds maximum object size '9223372036854775807'`. I wonder where that constraint comes from. Further dividing the size by 2 succeeds.

Comment: @TedLyngmo -- interesting. `sizeof(long[SIZE_MAX])` fails in both Clang 16.0.5 and GCC 12.2.0 due to the constraint violation. They both issue the same "array is too large" error. But `sizeof(char[SIZE_MAX])` does compile in Clang, just not in GCC. Maybe this is a bug in GCC?

Comment: @adabsurdum Or it may be open for being implementation defined. The bugzilla issue I read (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70588) mentioned putting a much much lower limit than `SIZE_MAX/2` in there, but currently, that compiles, while `SIZE_MAX/2+1` doesn't.

Comment: Even though the standard specifies that the maximal size of objects must be at most `SIZE_MAX`, it does not require an implementation to actually support objects of that size. The supported maximal object size may be smaller.

Comment: @nielsen I suspected that would be the case. Do you know if that's explicitly mentioned in the standard somewhere? Also, is an implementation that supports compiling `sizeof(char[SIZE_MAX])` also required to actually support objects of that size? I would think they are two different things.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I do not have a good reference, but the possibility is mentioned in the subsection "Recommended practice" in C23 (N3096) K.3.4. Intuitively, I agree that an implementation could support `sizeof` of objects larger than those supported. In any case, a "maximal size object" may only exist as a theoretical term since realizing such an object could easily exceed a system limitation (e.g. stack size). So even if the compiler may support an object of a given size, the target system may not.

Comment: Re “won't compile”: `sizeof (long [SIZE_MAX])` violates the constraint in 6.2.5 28, but that is not in a constraints paragraph, so the standard does not require the compiler to issue a diagnostic for it or not to compile it. If it will not compile, that is an implementation choice.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So it's ultimately up to the implementors then. It doesn't make the implementation non-conforming by setting an arbitrary upper limit (as long as any minimum limit is respected). Works for me.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- I overlooked that; so this actually has undefined behavior per the Standard, and GCC and Clang at least issue an error.

Comment: So in both cases (variable-length array and constant-expression) the behavior is undefined?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Actually I checked [N2596](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf) and [N3088](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3088.pdf) and N2596 does not have this constraint. It seems the issue was presented in earlier standards (at least c20)

Comment: To conclude the beahvior was well-defined prior C23, but become undefined starting C23

Comment: @SomeName _"...well-defined prior C23...."_ -- The Standards Committee views this as a clarification, not the introduction of new undefined behavior. It seems that they found that the prevailing interpretation was [_"that huge objects make the behavior implicitly undefined."_](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2838.htm) 6.2.5 now makes this explicit.

Comment: @adabsurdum Very interesting, since all the implementation used to treat such code to have UB implicitly, they just decided to make it explicit and added it to the Standard. But to be frank such implicit UB is not obvious at all and lots of folks (including me) used to think it was well-defined actually.

Answer (score 4):

> If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.

Yes, it's well defined. It performs the `sizeof(element)*number_of_elements` calculation at runtime for variable length arrays. It doesn't matter that the result is large.

And Barmar correctly mentioned:

> while it may be well defined, it might not be useful.

Comment: But there's a good chance that it will overflow (e.g. if `size_t == unsigned long`). So while it may be well defined, it might not be useful.

Comment: @Barmar Good point. I added your note!

Comment: @TedLyngmo the main source of confusion is that `sizeof(long[SIZE_MAX])` does not compile.

Comment: @SomeName That's not a variable length array though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hmm, indeed, but isn't the compile error a well-defined behavior or it depends on the implementation?

Comment: @SomeName Unsure.  I need to check that in the standard. All compilers I use refuses to compile that because it's too large, but I'm not sure if that's mandated by the standard.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The only point I can see is `6.5.3.4/p5`: _The value of the result of both operators is implementation-defined_ so the compile-error can be treated as an implementation defined behavior probably

Comment: @SomeName Seems like you landed closer to the truth than I did. :-) I got sidetracked and ended up in bugzilla on `SIZE_MAX/2` issues from way back. I think your own finding deserves an answer of its own since you actually stated _"The main issue I'm confused about..."_ from the start and your own finding seems to be the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

`size_t` is the type which must be large enough to accomodate the size of the largest possible object in your implementation. So it is well defined.

But if the real calculated size of your object (assuming infinitive integer size) is > `SIZE_MAX` it can't be created or used in your program. Then it is completely useless.

Comment: There will be an overflow anyway, but why don't compilers allow `sizeof(long[SIZE_MAX])`? It's rejected with a compile error...

Comment: Because this one is done compile time

Comment: Not clear why it's not an overflow. If the array size calculation is equivalent to `element_size * element_count` then there will be an overflow...

Comment: @SomeName unsigned integers do not overflow, only wraparound. And it is well defined behaviour,  **signed** integers overflow - is not. That is the difference.

Comment: Re “`size_t` is the type which must be large enough to accomodate the size of the largest possible object in your implementation”: The current C standards, C 2018, does not say that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The actual definition is provided by the Standard at `7.19`: _unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator_.

Comment: @SomeName: That says what the type is, not what values it must support. In general, operations in C can have mathematical results outside the bounds of their result types. What happens then depends on the type and certain other factors.

Answer (score 3):

> The main issue I'm confused about is that
>
> ```
> size_t sz = sizeof(long[SIZE_MAX]); //error: size of unnamed array is too large
> ```
>
> does not even compile

`SIZE_MAX` is a *constant expression* and can be evaluated during translation; it is the largest value that can be represented by `size_t`, so the compiler **knows** that an array of `SIZE_MAX` elements of any type other than `char` will exceed `SIZE_MAX` bytes and reject the code.  It can do this for any constant expression whose value is greater than `SIZE_MAX / sizeof (long)`.

`cnt` is *not* a constant expression, so `sizeof( long[cnt] )` isn't evaluated until *runtime* and the compiler can't flag it as a problem.

So what happens?

> **6.2.5 Types**
> ...
> 9 The range of nonnegative values of a signed integer type is a subrange of the corresponding unsigned
> integer type, and the representation of the same value in each type is the same.<sup>41)</sup> ***A computation
> involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the
> resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest
> value that can be represented by the resulting type.***

So, basically, `size_t sz = sizeof( long[cnt] )` will give you *some* value that's mod'ed by `SIZE_MAX`.  It won't be the size of the array in bytes; it will be some value that can fit in a `size_t`.  Well-defined, but not terribly useful.